# Bazel save preprocessed files

Tags: c++, build, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a BUILD file in my cpp project, that defines what is build. I have no clue in bazel, nor there it is being run from. Currently I either copy rules or add sources to existing rules, e.g., this is the rule where I want to add an action

```
cc_library(
    name = "cool_app",
    srcs = ["cool_app.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["cool_app.h"],
    deps = ["//modules/common"],
)
```

I want to produce a pre-processor output for `cool_app.h`. Are there options that could be added to this rule to achieve what I want?

UPDATE:
The content of `cool_app.h`:

```
#pragma once

#define ENUM_INIT_LIST \
    ADD_VALUE(First) \
    ADD_VALUE(Second) \

#define ADD_VALUE(topic) topic,
enum class Topic : int {
    Invalid = -1,
    TOPIC_INIT_LIST
    LAST_ENUM_ELEMENT,
};
#undef ADD_VALUE

#define ADD_VALUE(topic) Topic::topic,
constexpr auto kAvailableTopics =
    std::initializer_list<Topic>({TOPIC_INIT_LIST});
#undef ADD_VALUE
```

And I want to save a C pre-processor output, so humans can get something similar to:

```
#pragma once

enum class Topic : int {
    Invalid = -1,
    First,
    Second,
    LAST_ENUM_ELEMENT,
};

constexpr auto AvailableTopics =
    std::initializer_list<Topic>({
        Topic::First,
        Topic::Second,
    });
```

Comment: It might help to add an example of how you would normally "produce a pre-processor output for cool_app.h" from the command line without bazel? As it currently stands your question is a bit ambiguous, there are many ways to produce preprocessor outputs.

Comment: @silvergasp, currently I do not know. I see bazel allows flags like --save_temps, i.e. adding it to the command line. However, I do not control command line. Hence, this is not an option.

Comment: Ok so you can control the command line with bazel. But in order to help you do it with bazel we need to know what your actually trying to achieve. Can you give a specific example of what preprocessing means to you, in the context of this question?

Comment: @silvergasp, please see a simplified example